# Template function is running twice on the loading the webpage

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi guys do you know why the following function is calling twice when meteor start?

The first time `items` and `posts` variables result is 0 and then in the second run have the objects inside of them. I know this is maybe because the html render before the event, but that not answer why its running twice.

```
Template.postList.itemList = function()
{
    var items = Items.find().fetch();
    var posts = Posts.find().fetch();

    debugger;

    return Posts.find();
}
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the `next function`?

Comment: sorry I mean the Template.postList.itemList function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking about, but the `itemList` helper is first executed when the site is initially rendered. Note, that initially `Items` and `Post` collections contain no documents at all. As soon as some documents arrives from the server the template containing your helper will be rerendered, which causes the `itemList` function to be called for the second time.